MultiCamera Support fastdds
I am currently configuring a program to acquire 8-channel camera data.
The operating system I use is ros2 galactic.
The camera resolution is 2048*1280(UYVY) and supports 30fps.
I created a ros2 program and configured fastdds to measure topic hz. When I measure 7-channel topic hz, the CPU usage increases and the hz performance decreases.

When I proceeded with a different camera resolution of 1920*1080(UYVY) 30fps, the symptom did not appear.

The suspicious part is that the symptom appears when the data transfer amount exceeds 1GB.
Hi.
I am currently configuring a program to acquire 8-channel camera data.
The operating system I use is ros2 galactic.
The camera resolution is 2048*1280 and supports 30fps.
I created a ros2 program and configured fastdds to measure topic hz. When I measure 7-channel topic hz, CPU usage increases and hz performance decreases.
When I proceed with other camera resolutions of 1920*1080 30fps, the symptom does not appear.
The suspicious part is that the symptom appears when the data transfer amount exceeds 1GB.
Below is the fastdds configuration file.
Is there a limit to the transfer amount?
Below is the fastdds configuration file.
    <!-- We still want the default UDP transport to be present -->
    <transport_descriptor>
        <transport_id>udp_transport</transport_id>
        <type>UDPv4</type>
    </transport_descriptor>

    <!-- We want a customized version of the SHM transport -->
    <transport_descriptor>
        <transport_id>shm_transport</transport_id>
        <type>SHM</type>
        
        <!--
            Configure the size in bytes of the shared memory segment.
            On a Linux based system, you can get the maximum allowed value with
                $ sysctl -a | grep shmmax
        -->
        <segment_size>5242880</segment_size>
        
        <!--
            The following value should be lower than or equal to segment_size.
            The default value is shown here.
        -->
        <maxMessageSize>5242880</maxMessageSize>
    </transport_descriptor>

</transport_descriptors>

<participant profile_name="CustomParticipant"  is_default_profile="true">
    <rtps>
        <!--
            As customized versions of the default transports are used, the
            built-in ones should be disabled
        -->
        <useBuiltinTransports>false</useBuiltinTransports>

        <!-- Link the Transport Layer to the Participant -->
        <userTransports>
            <transport_id>udp_transport</transport_id>

            <!-- Comment the following line in order to disable the SHM transport -->
            <transport_id>shm_transport</transport_id>
        </userTransports>
    </rtps>
</participant>


I also tried dds tuning,and export FASTDDS_BUILTIN_TRANSPORTS=LARGE_DATA
 but the result was the same.
What should I do to analyze the exact cause?
